# connect producer flow to graph

Tags: akka-stream, reactive-kafka

I am new using akka streams kafka (and akka streams in general) . I am trying to construct a graph in order to publish a message to different topics. 
How can I connect the producer as flow in order to commit the processed messages ? I tried using Producer.flow but I can't get the `commitScaladsl`

```
object TestFoo {
  import akka.kafka.ProducerMessage.Message
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("test-kafka")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  val evenNumbersTopic = "even_numbers"
  val allNumbersTopic = "all_numbers"
  lazy val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer[Int])
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
    .withGroupId("group1")
    .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
  lazy val source =  Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(Set(evenNumbersTopic, allNumbersTopic)))
  val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(system,  new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer())
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
  val flow: RunnableGraph[NotUsed] = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    import akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Implicits._
    type TypedMessage =  Message[String, Int,CommittableOffset]
    val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[TypedMessage](2))
    val merge = b.add(Merge[TypedMessage](2))

    val evenFilter = Flow[TypedMessage].filter (  c => c.record.value() % 2 == 0)
    val justEven = Flow[TypedMessage].map{
      case Message(pr, offset) =>
      val r = new ProducerRecord[String, Int]("general", pr.value())
      Message(r, offset)
    }
    val allNumbers = Flow[TypedMessage].map{
      case Message(pr, offset) =>
      val r = new ProducerRecord[String, Int](allNumbersTopic, pr.value())
      Message(r, offset)
    }

    val toMsg = Flow[ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage[String, Int]].map{ msg =>
      val r = new ProducerRecord[String, Int]("general", msg.record.value())
      Message(r, msg.committableOffset)
    }
    source ~> toMsg ~> bcast

    bcast ~> evenFilter ~> justEven ~> merge
    bcast ~> allNumbers ~> merge
    merge ~> Producer.flow(producerSettings).mapAsync(producerSettings.parallelism) { result =>
      result.message.passThrough.commitScaladsl() //this doesn't compile, cannot get the .commitScaladsl()
    }
    ClosedShape 
  })}
```

Comment: At the moment this example is rigged with many other compilation errors. Could you amend it to make your compilation error easily reproducible?

Comment: @StefanoBonetti yes, I have updated the code with less compilation errors , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the GraphDSL, the compiler cannot infer the `PassThrough` type from the previous stage.
Try and explicitly pass the type parameters to the `Producer.flow` function, e.g.

```
merge ~> Producer.flow[K, V, CommittableOffset](producerSettings).mapAsync(producerSettings.parallelism) { result =>
  result.message.passThrough.commitScaladsl()
}
```

I have left `K` and `V` as unbound param, please fit there whatever key/value types your Producer is bound to produce. If you want the code above to be correctly wired, you'll need to match the `producerSettings` types with what comes from the merge stage. You'll need something like:

```
val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(system,  new StringSerializer(), new JsonSerializer[Int])
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
```

Comment: Thanks but it is actually yields the same results :
```val sink = Producer.flow[String, String, CommittableOffset](producerSettings).mapAsync(producerSettings.parallelism) { result =>
      result.message.passThrough.commitScaladsl() //still doesn't compile, cannot get the .commitScaladsl() 
    }```

Comment: to me it looks like the `producerSettings` types are `[String, String]`, but you're actually feeding it a record of type `[String, Int]`. I have amended the answer to suggest some more changes